# Expected value of a density function.

Tags: statistics

Daily total solar radiation for a specified location in Florida in October has a probability density function given by

$f(y)$ = $(3/32)(y-2)(6-y), 2 <= y <= 6$, and $0$ elsewhere.

with measurements in hundreds of calories. Find the expected daily solar radiation for October.

How do I go about solving this? Do I just find the expected value of the function? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  And you do this by 
$$\int_2^6 y f(y)\, dy$$

Comment: That what I was thinking, however the solutions manual gives me this http://imgur.com/CVSYXSw. Is that also a valid solution to the question? Is this just a misprint? Thank you